# Error when trying to move site to local MAMP

Tags: wordpress

I been a little stupid. I admit.

I just started creating and developing a new site using a live subdomain I had. So now I'm trying to move it off that live server to a local MAMP server, and then finally import it to the actual final domain.

1. I've downloaded all the WordPress files from the live server to the appropriate folder.
2. I then logged into the phpMyAdmin and exported the WP database. .zipped it and imported it into the local phpMyAdmin.
3. Created a new user with the db_username and db_password from wp-config.
4. Edited the "home" and "siteurl" in the wp_options table to http://localhost/foldername
5. Restarted MAMP.

But now when I point to that new local url in the browser I get an 404 Error, page not found. And all links stil points to the live domain. So content is still pulled from there and soon as I click a link.

I would grateful for any help. I'm really lost here.

Comment: are you able to login to your dashboard ?

Comment: Nope, it redirects me to the live url.

Comment: Have you updated you wp-config.php file to refer to your local database?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because the data from your database is using your "live URL".

I suggest that you do the following.

1. Export the live "DB SQL" dumb via phpMyAdmin.
2. Open the .sql using any text editor (notepad++, atom, sublime, etc..)
3. Use search and replace. Search for the live URL (http://www.live.com) and replace it with the local URL (http://localhost/cubo/).
4. Import the altered .sql in your localhost via phpMyAdmin.
5. Go to your localhost dashboard (wp-admin).
6. Go to permalinks
7. Click "Save" to force flush rewrite.

Comment: I will give it a go.

Shouldn't the URL be replace http://localhost/thefoldername ?

Comment: Yes. I only used "http://localhost" as example. You should use the url that opens the localhost homepage.

Comment: I got one step closer! I replaced the url with localhost, and I edited the wp-config to: 

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

Now the frontpage is loading, and the dashboard too. And when I hover over a link it is correctly pointing too localhost. 

But when I click a link in my navbar i get a new Error:

"Not Found

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server."

Have I forgot to update a wp file somewhere?

Comment: Can I ask the following?

1.] What is "homepage" url in your localhost?
2.] What's the URL where you see the "Not Found" error?

Comment: 1: http://localhost/cubo/

2: Every link in the navbar: http://localhost/cubo/nyheder/ & http://localhost/cubo/projekter/ & http://localhost/cubo/tegnestuen/ & http://localhost/cubo/kontakt/

3: So no links seems to work: http://localhost/cubo/projekter/hib-hoegskolen-i-bergen/ also fails.

Comment: It seems that the issue is with your permalinks. Try to do the following.

1. Go to the localhost dashboard (wp-admin)
2. Go to permalinks
3. Click "Save" button. This will force flush rewrite.

Comment: Don't do a search and replace on your database - a lot of data is saved as serialized arrays and this will break badly if you update that.

Comment: @SimonPollard Actually it doesn't break any data. The search and replace will only replace "strings" it won't break anything.

To the person who down voted, can you explain why the downvote?

Comment: @donMhi.co "If you do a search and replace on your entire database to change the URLs, you can cause issues with data serialization, due to the fact that some themes and widgets store values with the length of your URL marked." https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress